# Airflow (LocalExecutor) - Docker :: Job is failing with Log file does not exist

Tags: airflow

Airflow version: 1.10.9

Executor : LocalExecutor

Docket Setup

when job runs sometime we are getting following error. I have searched in web, many people faced this issue in celeryExecutor but we are using LocalExecutor(Docker setup). How can I resolve this problem?

```
*** Log file does not exist: /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow/logs/es_update_relevance_score/es_update_relevance_score/2020-05-14T16:26:06.062416+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://:8793/log/es_update_relevance_score/es_update_relevance_score/2020-05-14T16:26:06.062416+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Invalid URL 'http://:8793/log/es_update_relevance_score/es_update_relevance_score/2020-05-14T16:26:06.062416+00:00/1.log': No host supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach I've seen when running the `scheduler` and `webserver` in their own containers and using `LocalExecutor`:

1. Mount a host log directory as a volume into both the `scheduler` and `webserver` containers:

```
    volumes:
        - /location/on/host/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

2. Make sure the user within the airflow containers (usually `airflow`) has permissions to read and write that directory. If the permissions are wrong you will see an error like the one in your post.

This probably won't scale beyond `LocalExecutor` usage though.